# data not getting passed with prepareForSegue or pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pass-data

I have tried all the ways to pass this data between the view Controllers, both of which are modally represented as page sheet.

**in ViewController 1 .h**
——————————

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * updatableProduct ;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * updatableProduct ; //tried
```

**in ViewController 1 .m**
——————————

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{

static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
TailorOUCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.updateOrder.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.updateOrder addTarget:self action:@selector(nowUpdateOrder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

orderToUpdate = [orderQueryResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}


-(void)nowUpdateOrder:(id)sender{

UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
updatableProduct = [orderQueryResults objectAtIndex:(long)senderButton.tag];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"updateOrder" sender:updatableProduct];
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"updateOrder" sender:self]; //tried

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"updateOrder"]) {
    OUEditView * ouv = (OUEditView *)segue.destinationViewController;
    ouv.orderDetails = updatableProduct;
    [segue.destinationViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet];

}

}
```

**in ViewController 2 .h**
——————————

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * orderDetails ;
```

**in ViewController 2 .m**
——————————

```
@synthesize orderDetails;
```

**But the orderDetails = null in log**

Any Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add breakpoints or log statements to your code and see what's happening.

- Is prepareForSegue being called at all?
- Is the IF statement matching the identifier?
- Is the value in "updatableProduct" not nil?
- Are you checking the value of ouv.orderDetails in viewDidLoad or
  viewWillAppear, instead of in the init method? (The init method fires
  before prepareForSegue is called.)

Comment: where should i call ouv.orderDetails ?, viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

Comment: The viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad are getting fired up even before the prepareForSegue and the strange thing is the order of operation.. prepareForSegue > nowUpdateOrder > prepareForSegue >. then the viewDidAppear of other window .. and the still here the value is null in viewDidAppear.